# How to install Android sdk on RHEL linux with platform and build tools

Tags: android, linux, build, compilation, apk

I am fairly new to android and i need to setup env to build the packages (not develop from a rhel linux machine.

I need to install android sdk on a RHEL linux machine (not ubuntu) where i cant open sdk manager to download the platform tools and build tools. Please let me know if some body has done that. This is required for compilation and build process. The error i am getting while trying to update the platform is there are no available target.

My basic requirement is to set up environment to build and generate the apk package( The code is developed by the developers and my requirement is to just compile and build the packages)

```
$ android list target  
Available Android targets:
```

---

```
$ android update sdk -u  
Refresh Sources:  
  Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml  
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully  
  Refresh Sources  
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml  
Refresh Sources:  
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml  
Refresh Sources:  
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml  
Refresh Sources:  
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml  
There is nothing to install or update.
```

Comment: Maybe this? https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/HOWTO_Setup_Android_Development#Install_Android_SDK

Comment: no, this doesnt work, i need ateast one build tools inside platform directory

Comment: Not sure what you mean... don't you just download a particular SDK version to get the build tools?

Comment: Thanks This issue is resolved, i came to know that my proxies were not allowed to connect to dl.google.com and it worked after i got the proxies working

Answer (score 0):

You can download Android SDK tools with this URL:

### Versions can be found here :

#### https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml

Here is a small script to do that :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS=$1 #25.2.3
ANDROID_SDK_PLATFORM_TOOLS=$2 #25.0.3
ANDROID_SDK_BUILD_TOOLS=$3 #25.0.2
ANDROID_PLATFORM=$4 #25_r03

wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r${ANDROID_SDK_PLATFORM_TOOLS}-linux.zip
wget http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r${ANDROID_SDK_BUILD_TOOLS}-linux.zip
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}-linux.zip
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-${ANDROID_PLATFORM}.zip
```